# Subroutine C++ called from Fortran : How to deal with Dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, fortran

I currently have a C++ program which performs some tasks (not important here) and store some data into a 2D array which has been dynamically allocated (using C function malloc). It works well and I now need to have access to these data in a fortran program. I'm currently creating a program in Fortran which calls a subroutine in C/C++ performing the tasks I want, but when the 2D dynamically array is filled with data, I need to have access to it when back to the Fortran main program.
The problem is I can't manage to get my data back to the Fortran main program (in an 2D allocatable array)
I tried to code a simple program for passing a dynamic array allocated in a C subroutine, which is called by my main Fortran program, in order to see if I can get access to the data when I'm out of the C subroutine.

Here is my small code :

**Fortran main:**

```
PROGRAM FORT_C

use iso_c_binding
IMPLICIT NONE

interface
    subroutine call_fc(pX,s) bind(C,name='call_fc_')
        import
        integer(c_int)              :: s
        type(c_ptr), allocatable    :: pX
    end subroutine
end interface

integer(c_int)                              :: i
integer(c_int), pointer                     :: X(:)
type(C_ptr), allocatable                    :: pX


call call_fc(pX,100)
call c_f_pointer(pX,X,[100])

END
```

**C subroutine:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" 
{
    void call_fc_(int **x, int s);
    void c_func_deallocate(int **x);
}


void call_fc_(int **x, int s)
{
    int i;
    *x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*s);
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        *x[i]=i;
    }
}

void c_func_deallocate(int **x)
{
    free(*x);
}
```

This is really simple, but I get this **output:**

```
0
1
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
exemple            000000000040304C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exemple            0000000000402F25  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exemple            0000000000402ECC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          000000331241ECDD  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exemple            0000000000402DC9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

I don't understand why I get this when i>1
I hope I was clear on my problem, can someone help please ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `*x[i]=i;` means `*(x[i])=i;`, but what you want is `(*x)[i]=i;`.

This happens because both `x[i]` and `*x` are pointers to `int`, so the compiler can't catch the error.
(`*x[i]` is equivalent to `x[i][0]`, while `(*x)[i]` is equivalent to `x[0][i]`.)

To avoid the issue, and the parentheses, you can rewrite like this:

```
void call_fc_(int **x, int s)
{
    int i;
    int *y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*s);
    for(i = 0; i < 100 && i < s; i++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        y[i]=i;
    }
    *x = y;
}
```

I added a test for `i < s` in order to avoid writing outside the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in fact the segfault no more appears, it was tricky !
But I have another problem now, it seems I have access to a larger amount of memory than allocated with malloc. I show the whole code (which is small) because I also performed some changes (put *s instead of s for example), and the output.

Comment: **Fortran:**

    PROGRAM FORT_C
    use iso_c_binding
    IMPLICIT NONE

     interface
      subroutine call_fc(pX,s) bind(C,name='call_fc_')
       import
       integer(c_int)     :: s
       type(c_ptr), allocatable :: pX
      end subroutine
     end interface
    
     integer(c_int)         :: i
     integer(c_int)         :: s
     integer(c_int), pointer      :: X(:)
     type(C_ptr), allocatable     :: pX
    
     s=100

     call call_fc(pX,s)
     call c_f_pointer(pX,X,(/s/))

    END

Comment: **C subroutine:**

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    
    using namespace std;

    extern "C" 
    {
        void call_fc_(int **x, int *s);
     void c_func_deallocate(int **x);
    }


    void call_fc_(int **x, int *s)
    {
        int *y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*(*s));
        for(int i=0; i < *s+10; i++)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            y[i]=i;
        }
        *x = y;
    }

    void c_func_deallocate(int **x)
    {
     free(*x);
    }


**Outpout:**

    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9

Comment: I wanted to get a segfault when trying to access out of the allocated space, but it seems not to disturb it... Why is that ?
Again thank you for your answer, it's very helpful !

Comment: Sorry for the shape of the comments, I just can't post an answer for the next 8 hours as a regular user...

Comment: Since this leads to undefined behaviour, and undefined means that anything can happen, "not crash" is also something a program is allowed to do in this case. The program is still invalid. (Why the sudden unmotivated pointer for `s`?)

Comment: Ok so it's just my work to ensure the validity of the boundaries, thanks !
I thought when calling a C subroutine from fortran, it gets a pointer to the variables, am I right?
In the loop after malloc, I had thousands of iterations when I put the condition "i<s" only. I seems that s was the address of the variable, that's why I thought of the pointer. When correcting it, it worked fine

Comment: I'm facing another problem though.. Sorry, I'm really new to language mixing !
I inserted this code in the fortran file:
`do i=1,s
 write(*,*), i
 write(*,*) X(i)
end do`
after the call `call c_f_pointer(pX,X,(/s/))` in order to see if I have access to the data in the fortran part, but I get a segfault immediately.. Seems that I don't get access to the array, do you see the problem here? Thanks for your time !

Comment: I'm afraid I have no clue about Fortran at all (that's how I missed the pointer issue). I think it would be best if you post a new question.

Comment: Ok I'll post a new question.. Your answers were very useful, thank you molbdnilo !

Answer (score 2):

Amongst other things, your interface in Fortran for the C++ function declares the pX argument to be allocatable.  Note support for this requires a compiler that supports that feature from the future F201X standard.  There aren't many of those.

I very much suspect this isn't what you intend - but if you did the C++ argument declaration is quite different from what you have.  Consult the TS for further interoperability with C for more information.

You don't need or want pX to be allocatable, either as the variable in the main program or the argument.  You are not "allocating" pX - it is a C_PTR that you want to define with the C address of some memory allocated by your C++ function.

Also, the `s` argument in the interface is declared without the VALUE attribute.  That means that it corresponds to a pointer argument on the C side.  Your C definition shows it being passed by value.

Comment: Thank you for answering IanH, concerning the `s` argument, I corrected it (as mentionned in the previous comments). Regarding pX, I changed "allocatable" to "pointer" (also mentionned in the previous comment, sorry for the structure of the code inside the comments, I had no other choice). I'm really new in mixing the two languages so I apologize if I write dummy things! What I intended to declare in Fortran was kind of a pointer to get access to the array allocated in the C subroutine. Do you have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: A "kind of pointer" in Fortran that is the same as a pointer in C is just a C_PTR - you don't want the POINTER attribute on the dummy argument in the interface body.  Fortran POINTERs are "different" to C pointers in a few ways - that's why you use C_F_POINTER to convert a C pointer in Fortran to a Fortran POINTER.

Comment: I removed the POINTER attribute, now it works fine. I'm starting to understand how to deal with dynamic memory when mixing Fortran and C.. Thank you for helping !